# How to retrieve the download Url after uploading image to Firebase storage, so that I can save it to Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic3, firebase-storage

The code below successfully uploads images to Firebase storage, but I want to retrieve the downloadURL of that exact image and store it in "this.pichaMtumiaji" and later save it in Firebase database. I'm using ionic 3!

```
uploadPhoto(): void {
    this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('myPhoto.png')
      .putString(this.myPhoto, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/png' })
      .then((savedPicture) => {
        this.pichaMtumiaji = savedPicture.downloadURL().absoluteString;
      });
  }

generateUUID(): any {
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
    var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    d = Math.floor(d / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
  });
  return uuid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample in the [Firebase documentation on uploading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#full_example):

```
var ref = this.myPhotosRef.child(this.generateUUID()).child('myPhoto.png');
ref
  .putString(this.myPhoto, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/png' })
  .then((savedPicture) => {

    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
    ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
      this.pichaMtumiaji = savedPicture.downloadURL().absoluteString;
    });

  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but your solution does not solve the problem either. As stated before, even after your solution, the image gets saved to Firebase storage but the download URL is still not attainable.

Comment: Please be more specific than "is still not attainable". What happens when you run the code? Does it log "File available at"? Did you run it in a debugger? Did you set a  breakpoint on `ref.getDownloadURL()...`? Does it get triggered? Did you set a breakpoint on `this.pichaMtumiaji...`? What is the value you get there?

Comment: I run it in debugger and here is what I got:

    `vendor.js:2134 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'pichaMtumiaji' of 
    undefined
    at main.js:224
    at e.g (vendor.js:140665)
    at Fb (vendor.js:140668)
    at Bb (vendor.js:140668)
    at A.g.Yb (vendor.js:140667)
    at kb (vendor.js:140661)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:5445)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)`

Comment: OK. So `this` is undefined it seems.

Comment: Yes! How I am I supposed to fix it..? I have declared it in the beginning `public pichaMtumiaji: any;` but it seems not to to be the solution.

Comment: It should be defined on the same object where you defined `myPhotosRef`. But that part is missing from the code you supplied.

Comment: This is where I defined ` myPhotosRef ` in my code:
`export class BoreshaWasifuPage {
  
  pichaMtumiaji: string;
  public myPhotosRef: any;
  public myPhoto: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public usajiliHuduma: UsajiliHuduma, public mtumiajiHuduma: MtumiajiHuduma,
    public imagePicker: ImagePicker, public cropHuduma: Crop, public camera: Camera,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
      this.myPhotosRef = firebase.storage().ref('/pichaWatumiaji/');
    }`
Help please!

Comment: I'm trying to help here, but Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and make sure that you question contains the minimal-but-complete code that reproduces the problem, any error messages, and relevant data. That will for example show us how the code from your comment relates to the code you already shared.